# Selling a literature study guide

Tags: copyright

Can I create and sell a literature study guide for a copyright protected fiction book? I quote fewer than 300 words from the fiction book, but I could easily omit the quotes altogether. The guide teaches literature conventions and critical thinking through questions inspired by the story, games, projects, art activities, and other activities inspired by the story.

Answer (score 10):

This almost certainly falls under fair use. In fact, there are numerous examples of such books already.

You are using a small portion of the work, and it is for a transformative purpose- teaching about it.